# Converting Optional String to Int in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a call from my JSON file where the variable is a string however in order to compare it I would want it to be an integer, however, whenever I try and convert it using methods on here nothing seems to be working, assuming the wrong syntax. This line essentially (pData.info?.nutriScore ?? 0) prints a score however its a string.

```
if let nScore = Int(pData.info?.myScore ?? 0) < 0 {
           //Other Code   
       }
```

Comment: What is the value of `nutriScore`?

Comment: What type is `pData`, what type is `info` and what type is `nutriScore`?

Comment: You should check value before converting between types, not convert types and then check for value (like the answers below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
if let nScore = Int(pData.info?.myScore ?? "0" ) , nScore > 0 {

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `nScore < 0` ?

Comment: This solution treats no score the same as a score of zero, in case that is significant to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
if let nutriScore = pData.info?.nutriScore, let nScore = Int(nutriScore) {
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: I get this when I do that Value of optional type 'Int?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Int'

Answer (score 1):

```
if let nScore:Int = Int(pData.info?.nutriScore ?? "0") {
        if nScore < 0 {
            print(nScore)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using ?? default value ,

Yes you dont have the value in your object so you are passing the default that doesnt mean default value is your Real data .

```
    if let b = pData.info?.myScore, let nScore = Int(b) , nScore >= 0{
        print(nScore)
    } else {// handle negative logic}
```